# Topic for Thesis | Testing in a Spring/Hybris-enviorment

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, tdd, project-management

So I currently have an internship in a company, which has a Web-Shop implemented with Hybris and Spring. When my internship ends in a month, I will have three months to write my thesis. Of course I would like to do this in this company. So I need to write and do something, of which the company gets an advantage. Plus it needs to specific, it should be not too hard for three months, but also not too easy.

Since I already got to know, that the company wants to go more in the Test Driven Development direction, and they currently have only few Unit-tests for all the classes, I would like to do a topic in this field.

But how can I find a good topic? I thought about doing an analysis of the current situation, with risk-analysis and so on, and then try to do something to do improve it.

The problem is, that this is just too unspecific. So my question would be, if you guys would know any way to specify it, or know of something I can do, since Test Driven Development is new to me.

What about concentrating on Unit-tests? First do an analysis, of the coverage, and then write some Unit-tests for the most important classes? But this sounds too simple.

Really any advice whatsoever is very appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't say. That's why i am having problem, finding a good topic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should suggest to:

- implement Continuous integration with test coverage reports
- write a TDD guideline for new code (forget about Hybris out of the box code), so every time dev write a new service / controller / DAO / ... they need to actually write the test before
- Have a rule for your CI saying that if the global test coverage is decreasing then the build fails

My personal opinion here is that there are tons of books / articles about TDD, for your thesis you should add something more valuable:

- Identify when and where in the code they find regressions
- classify them (UI / Core / DAO / Services)